# how to add new column in ROR 3.0 once i completed rake db:migrate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-migrations

hi i m new ruby on rails 3.0 i want know how create new column one i migrated file

i created migration using

```
rake db:migrate 

class CreateCheckings < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change

    create_table :checkings do |t|

         t.string :phone, :limit => 20
          t.string  :email 
        t.integer  "country_id"
            t.string   "registration_via"
            t.string   "industry_type", :limit => 2
            t.boolean  "is_admin",              :default => false
            t.boolean  "is_account_blocked",    :default => false   

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

table are created now new to add some some column how can i do with terminal plz help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In terminal

```
rails g migration add_column_name_to_table_name column_name:type

rails g migration add_columns_to_tables
```

Answer (score 2):

run
`rails g migration add_column_name_to_table_name column_name:type` or
create one migration `rails g migration add_columns_to_tables` then

```
def change
    add_column :table_name, :column_name, :type
end
```

refer http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html,
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Migration.html